# Artifactory - "Set Me Up" shows wrong URL

Tags: artifactory

I am running an artifactory (v4) instance. When clicking via gui on artifacts there is a "set me up" button which shows you the repository url in which an artifact is located.

This URL is wrong in my case. It is a https:// but it should be normal http://
Can someone tell me in which hidden .xml file I can fix this wrong url?

Answer (score 5):

The url that used in "set me up" and other links in JFrog's Artifactory is configured by [Custom Base URL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifactory#ConfiguringArtifactory-GeneralSettings).
Go to "admin" > "configuration" > "general" and change it there to `http://your-server/artifactory`.